# Failing to run an existing project

Tags: angular, http, npm, angular-in-memory-web-api

I am starting with section 6 of Google's Tour of Heroes : "Get data from a server".

It seems that messages said I succeeded with installing InMemoryDataService and HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule, which was much more difficult on another machine a few years ago (this one has 64 GB memory, possibly it helps). Nevertheless, the following calls for carefulness.

A problem arises when trying to execute : "Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path "" must have required property 'browserTarget'."

Did I skip any step?

If somebody has a solution for this I am interested, but threads were opened on that topic three years ago, and still not closed, so I tried something else that should occasionnate no problem : in order to operate a comparison with something that works I downloaded toh-pt6 at the beginning of the section, and this time when trying to execute I was said that it is impossible to start debugging. I am invited to verify that the project is the default project of the solution, which is the case, and then to verify the options of the project.

I tried to run `npm install` myself, but it answered this:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: angular.io-example@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@17.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"17.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^16.0.0" from angular-in-memory-web-api@0.16.0
npm ERR! node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api
npm ERR!   angular-in-memory-web-api@"~0.16.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-11-30T12_17_35_795Z-eresolve-report.txt
```

I noticed that the online version took more than half an hour to build, and still did not succeed, unless I was too impatient?
Does anybody have any suggestion?

---

Essentially the log repeats the same information, and adds:
"Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
"

I presume I am not the first one to get through this section, so perhaps somebody has an opinion about whether this force option is a good idea.

Comment: upgrade angular-in-memory-web-api to 0.17.0 e.g. `npm install angular-in-memory-web-api@latest --save`

Comment: which version of NodeJS do you use?

Comment: Oh, very interesting, when I ask `ng version` : I have to specify a command before "moving on". But am I said that? Nothing tells that I have to move on before getting the version number, or I should not have understood what it means.

Comment: Angular CLI: 17.0.3
Node: 18.18.0
Package Manager: npm 9.8.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 17.0.4
Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1700.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular   16.2.10
@angular-devkit/core            17.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics      17.0.3
@angular/cli                    17.0.3
@schematics/angular             17.0.3
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.2.2
zone.js                         0.14.2

Comment: I gave no precision to install the components, so it was installed with the default version. And I imagine it is also the case for Google's version.

Comment: C:\Projects Visual Studio\Web\Angular_23_32\Angular_23_32\src\app>npm install angular-in-memory-web-api@latest --save

"Too long by 732 characters". 
But I have about the same errors as before.

Comment: Oh, I have to be more selective ...
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@16.2.12

Comment: npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@16.2.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^16.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.10
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^16.2.10" from the root project